# Command line argument to run my own script

Tags: python

I have written a code function.py in python which has input file path and a output file path and some flags . currently I have hardcoded everything.I want to use command line arguments to provide these inputs so that anyone can run my script by providing input to cmd.how can I do it in python?
In CMD
function.py "input file path" "output file path"

Comment: Look at sys.argv. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: You didn't share any code, but I assumed you already use `sys.argv`, you should look at `argparse` for a fairly flexible, yet still sufficiently simple way of implementing command line options that match how most application present and process them.

Comment: +1 for `argparse`. I use it all the time in preference to `sys.argv` any time I write a script that takes arguments on the command line.

Comment: Sorry,I can't share the script..Do I have to embed extra lines of argparse in my main script (function.py) at top or I have to write it separately in some other file and call my function.py function from this file?

Answer (score 1):

A very rudimentary example would be:

```
import sys

input_file_path = sys.argv[1]
output_file_path = sys.argv[2]
```

Note that `sys.argv[0]` would be your filename. You should also do the relevant checks to make sure there are the correct number of arguments, whether they are valid, etc.

Comment: Where should I write these lines .should I write it at top of the script which I want to run or in a different file which will call my script?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `sys.argv`, I prefer [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

As an example:

```py
# Import the argparse module
import argparse
    
# Define a function to use argparse to parse your command-line arguments
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--input-file",
        dest="input_file",
        help="File to use as input",
        type=str
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-o",
        "--output-file",
        dest="output_file",
        help="File to output to",
        type=str
    )

    return parser.parse_args()

# If calling this module from the command line, this `if` statement will evaluate to True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Parse your command-line arguments
    args = parse_args()

    # Get the parsed value of the "-i" argument:
    infile = args.input_file

    # Get the parsed value of the "-o" argument:
    outfile = args.output_file
```

Comment: I have many variables in my script.how python will know that input file path goes correctly in input file path variable.suppose I have 10 variables and I need to set these 2 variables only using command line argument.how to do it?

Comment: @Alpha432, the command to run the file would be then: `python main.py --input-file <path> --output-file <path>` or it can also be  `python main.py -i <path> -o <path>`. 

I have assumed that you file is main.py here. change it accordingly.

Comment: @Alpha432, for an example on how to use these in the file, check out [this](https://github.com/shubhlohiya/CS747-FILA-reinforcement-learning/blob/master/cs747-pa3/main.py) code I wrote a while ago that takes command line args.

Comment: @ShubhamLohiya can you please tell me where should I write these command line arguments of argparse .should o write it at top of my main script or I have to create a new script

Comment: Do like I did in my answer and define it as a function. Then call the function (with `args = parse_args()`) when you need your script to parse the arguments you gave to your script on the command-line

Comment: @Alpha432 - I've edited my answer to give a bit more detail